# is not defined has no method 'map'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I keep getting these bizarre errors when running one particular function, and I can't figure it out.  Here's the set up.

```
MyObject.prototype._activate = function() {
...
}

...

encode = function(data) {
    var str;
    str = data.map(function(d) {
        return String.fromCharCode(d)
    }).join("");
    return btoa(str).replace(/.{76}(?=.)/g, '$&\n');
}

var mystring = encode(somedata);
```

The error happens on the data.map line and it is this:

Uncaught TypeError: Object ReferenceError: _activate is not defined has no method 'map'

Of course the MyObject has absolutely nothing to do with the encode method.  I've put a breakpoint on data.map and data is an Array.  It has nothing to do with MyObject or _activate, so I wonder if this is a Chrome bug in reporting the error or what is going on.

EDIT:  More information. I also had this in my code:

```
var instance = new MyObject();

var encoded = encode(somedata);

instance.load(encoded);
```

If I comment out the line instance.load(encoded) I do not receive the error.  It makes me think encode() is not happening synchronously...

Comment: Could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The error reads as though `somedata` is the string "Object ReferenceError: _activate is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, arrays and objects are often interchangeable, e.g. the following should give the same:

```
alert(a.mem);
alert(a["mem"]);
```

Given that the `map` function is being called, I would expect `data` to be an array conceptually anyway.

[Map was impletemented in JavaScript 1.6 and standardised ECMA 5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/map) so I would expect [browser support for it to be limited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions) (at the time of writing).

It could be that a side-effect of these limitations is causing this.

Comment: data is the correct array, I've seen it in the debugger.  It is a large image, an array of many bytes.  There is no confusing it.

Comment: If I implied it wasn't then i didn't mean to. Really I was just trying to point out that it might be browser incompatibility issues.

Comment: Your first sentence is very misleading, Array and Object are a different data-type in javascript. What you are refering to is the synthax that you can use to access the data inside an array or an object that is similar. In no way that makes Object and Array interchangeable.

Comment: @HoLyVieR uh actualy array is just an extension of object... try this in your browser `typeof []`

Comment: @HoLyVieR - "In JavaScript, arrays are objects" - JavaScript: The Good Parts. By Douglas Crockford. Anyway, this is somewhat divergent from the original question.

Comment: @James @Greg An apple is fruit, but a fruit isn't necessarily an apple. Array extends Object, but that doesn't make them the same thing. My point still stands.

Comment: @James, I doubt it's browser incompatibility, I'm using Chrome 12.